# compile c problem in emacs (ubuntu)

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I wrote a very simple program like: ( sorry, I typed the code in the right way, but the display is wired. How could I fix it?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
   int i;

   for ( i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {
      printf( "%d hello!\n", i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Usually, I compile c program in terminal with the command

cc -o xxx xxx.c

So in Emacs, when I type M-x compile, I change make -k to cc -o.
But I got error like

cc: argument to '-o' is missing

What's the problem?

If I use make, then I still got error

No targets specified and no makefiles found.

Finally, if the above problem is fixed, how could I define a custom hotkey for compile?
I have already know how to do something like

global-set-key [f8] 'goto-line

But I don't know to set a hotkey for an action only for c-mode.

Comment: thanks hilal, could you tell me how to fix the display problem? I checked it, but it seems almost the same as I typed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (if you're not blocking javascript from googleapis.com, then there's a bright orange question mark at the top right of the editing form which links to this).

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply the entire cc line.

"make -k" assumes that you have a Makefile supplying the commands to make things.

So, replace make -k with

```
cc -o xxx xxx.c
```

As for the emacs binding:

```
(global-set-key [f6] 'compile)
```

Comment: thanks. it works great. although it's not necessary, but curious that is it possible to do that: set default compile command to cc -o (I have seen this);  press f6, then directly compile the current file (without typing xxx.c) and gives the output file as xxx (don't need to specify the output filename)? ( or how to use make to do similar thing?)

Comment: Emacs has a full featured LISP interpetter, so it's possible, and prolly not hard. You might ask about it, or better yet spend some time learning elisp. I can't say off the top of my head, it's been a couple of years since I looked at customization in emacs.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to build simple one file programs like this is to add values for the compile-command variable at the top of the file, like this:

```
// -*- compile-command:"g++ helloworld.cpp -g -o helloworld.exe"; -*-
```

There's more detail about this in my blog post ["Writing quick C++ programs in emacs without a makefile"](http://justinsboringpage.blogspot.com/2009/05/writing-quick-c-programs-in-emacs.html)

Answer (score 0):

try changing make -k to make xxx.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way of doing it is like it is documented for the variable `compile-command` (which is the one used by `compile`, normally containing `make -k`).

Do `C-h v compile-command` to see the documentation for the variable. It contains some code that you can change to your liking.